# GWT: How can I get the size of a Composite inside HorizontalPanel

Tags: gwt, web

I'm using GWT and hava a class that extends Composite as a member of HorizontalPanel. How can I get the size of the Composite inside the constructor (it can not be passed as a parameter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the size of a block level element until it is attached to the DOM.

`Widget` has an [addAttachHandler(...)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#addAttachHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.AttachEvent.Handler%29) method. In the attach handler is the earliest you will be able to grab the size of your widget.

Comment: Actually the earliest is overriding onLoad() method of widget. It is called before the AttachEvent is fired.